# close button overlap scrollbar (position:fixed)

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

I'd like to fixed position right of the div inside the scrollable div.

But the fixed div just overlaps the parent div's scrollbar!
How to fix it?

(must be `fixed`, only `css`)

```
div {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto
}

div a {
    position:fixed;
    right:15px;
    top:15px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%
}
```

Comment: Provide us a demo, like a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase your right pixels little more to move the button. Here is the updated CSS for your reference.

```css
div {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto
}

div a {
    position:fixed;
    right:25px;
    top:15px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the scroll bar is on the body (which is the default behaviour when the page content is long), the fixed position div will not overlap on the scroll bar.

In your case, most likely the scroll bar is of one of the elements with `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;` or alike, that's why that div is overlapping.

Since we don't know what's your full HTML/CSS, we cannot tell which one is causing the issue or how to fix it.